# Apple universal links not working even after uploading Apple-app-site-assocaiton(AASA) file on server

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

I tried to implement universal links functionality in my app. For that I created a Apple-app-site-assocaiton(AASA) with in verified json format by branch.io and uploaded on my root server. After that I enable associated domains in my app capability in Xcode to define (applinks:) that help website url to detect my app into the active device. Now, problem is after implementation I could not avail that functionality as Web url not detecting my app. I tried so many trouble shooting method but it hasn't help me out.
Secondly, apple api validator tool is also not showing my website compatible to deep link even after successfully adding AASN file. Can anybody help where exactly I'm lacking behind.

Comment: Do you try to use firebase dynamic link instead of own universal link?

Comment: Can you post the link to your site association file?

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz I implemented it and its working but I want to implement universal links.

Comment: @PeteMorris https://so.city/apple-app-site-association